# Improving performance of distinct + groupByKey on Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to learn spark and came up with this problem but my solution doesn't seem to be performing well.  I was hoping someone can educate me on how I can improve the performance.  The problem I have is as follows.

I have a few million tuples (e.g. (A, B), (A, C), (B, C), etc.) with possibly duplicate tuples (keys and value).  What I would like to do is group up the tuples by key AND, to make it more interesting, limit the length of the grouped values to some arbitrary number (let's say 3).

So, for example, if I have:

```
[(A, B), (A, C), (A, D), (A, E), (B, C)]
```

I would expect the output to be:

```
[(A, [B, C, D]), (A, [E]), (B, [C]))
```

If any of the values for the list got longer than 3, then it would split it and you the same key listed multiple times as shown above with (A, [E]).  Hopefully this makes sense.

The solution I came up with was:

```
val myTuples: Array[(String, String)] = ...
sparkContext.parallelize(myTuples)
            .distinct()             // to delete duplicates
            .groupByKey()           // to group up the tuples by key
            .flatMapValues(values => values.grouped(3)) // split up values in groups of 3
            .repartition(sparkContext.defaultParallelism)
            .collect()
```

My solution works okay but is there a more efficient way to do this?  I hear that groupByKey is very inefficient.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, is there a good number I should choose for partitions? I noticed that `distinct` takes in a `partition` parameter but not sure what I should have put.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-formulate your problem slightly, as you aren't actually grouping by a single key here; in your example above, you output multiple rows for "A". In the below, I add a column which we can use additionally to group by (it will increment every 3 records), and collect_list which is a Spark SQL function to produce the arrays you are looking for. Note that by sticking to entirely Spark SQL, you get many optimisations from Spark (through "catalyst" which is a query optimiser).

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val data = List(("A", "B"), ("A", "C"), ("A", "D"), ("A", "E"), ("B", "C")).toDF("key","value")

val data2 = data.withColumn("index", floor(
  (row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("key").orderBy("value"))-1)/3)
)
data2.show

+---+-----+-----+
|key|value|index|
+---+-----+-----+
|  B|    C|    0|
|  A|    B|    0|
|  A|    C|    0|
|  A|    D|    0|
|  A|    E|    1|
+---+-----+-----+

data2.groupBy("key","index").agg(collect_list("value")).show

+---+-----+-------------------+
|key|index|collect_list(value)|
+---+-----+-------------------+
|  B|    0|                [C]|
|  A|    0|          [B, C, D]|
|  A|    1|                [E]|
+---+-----+-------------------+
```

Comment: I note you didnt explictly say you wanted to get rid of the duplicates. use a .distinct right at the start if you want to eliminate them. There is no partition argument for DataFrames on the distinct method (if you can use dataframes instead of rdds, in general this is normally going to be the correct choice due to the optimisations you get from catalyst).

Comment: Thanks @Nick for the help.  This is great.  Yes, the reason the output contained multiple 'A's was because of the limitation that the the values should have a length less than or equal to 3.  Right now, I am using a dataset (RDD) instead of a data frame.  Are there any cons (specific to this example) to using dataframes instead of dataset?

Comment: RDD's and Datasets are actually different things. To prove this to you, try running myTuples.toList.toDS() . To your question here, yes there is an advantage - you use the catalyst optimiser. Catalyst is there so that you don't have to worry about writing every query in the most efficient way (e.g. Spark will only read columns off disk it needs, it avoids un-necessary data structures ,...). The scope of fully explaining RDD vs DataFrame vs Dataset is several Stackoverflows in itself, but there's plenty on google explaining differences.